# How to fetch the text associated for those input tags for my elements in array

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" value="2" name="Type" class="cls" text="all">
<input type="text" value="1" name="Type" class="cls" text="few">
```

trying to get the text of these fields like:

```
labelValue = $('input[type=checkbox][name=Type][value ="' + values  + '"]').text();
```

Problem Stmt-  The problem here is i can select the value from drop down based on my search also at that time if i search abc i need to get the text of previous selection and current selection that was the reason i am taking the reference of global array

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: i had shared the code which i tried

Comment: @testusernewn use for loop to iterate over array

Comment: can anybody help me out

Answer (score 0):

use a loop/each/etc 
for example:

```
var values = ["40257", "40311", "40532", "40263"];

$.each(values, function(i, val){
   var theText = $(`input.cls[value="${val}"]`).attr("text");
   $('dropdownselector').append(`<option>${theText}</option>`);

});
```

Comment: attached the image

Comment: First, edit your question to show the code you have tried. It benefits the community and anyone that may have similar questions. Second, post a reference to the screenshot in the comments, not the answer. I can edit the answer if need be. Finally, I think I see the issue (typo) but can't be sure based on what I am seeing. Update your question and I can address it

Comment: $.each(values, function (i, val) {
                   var theText = $('input.cls[value = "' + values+ '"]').attr("text"); });  this is what i tried

Comment: attached the image to my question only

Comment: you should be using val, not values. values is the array, val is the value of the iteration. Look at my example closely

Comment: i was saying the same pblm i have ["40257", "40311", "40532", "40263"] and on debugging $.each(values, function(i, val){ values store all the array values and val will hold the value of current checked item in the drop down so now var theText = $(`input.cls[value="${val}"]`).attr("text");
val holds only current value and only that value gets binded to dropdown but i need to bind previous values also along with the current value

Comment: Append the dropdown list in the loop.